# Curl and http get - additional features

Tags: javascript, php, curl

everyone

I am noob with php and looking foward to figure out some sort of things.

I have perfectly working curl, but I need to add some features because that's is just simple code.

I need help to add container/panel where you just write car number and get results.

I have script, where already is inside a car reg number so it's automatically appears with results.

```html
<?php


    $vrm = "SK54OOV";
    $timeStamp = time();
    $apiKey = "xxxxx"; (not for u)
    $privateKey = "xxxxx";(not for u)

    $sig = sha1($apiKey.$privateKey.$timeStamp).dechex($timeStamp);

    $curl = curl_init();

    $headers = array(
    'Accept: text/xml',
    'AUTOGURU_API_KEY: '.$apiKey,
    'AUTOGURU_API_SIGNATURE: '.$sig
    );

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://localhost/somethings?vrm='.$vrm,
    ));

    $resp = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    echo $resp;

?>
```

Second things, is that I get results with curl, but they appear like that

```html
SK54OOVJHMCN15204C21297921250GBRC0090001FA00BAARAL4FTI040220410316BCFDC0505OTHER02670022004122005HON1436126199HOAC22SPO4SDTM 126200HOAC22SP74SDTM 112004-09-012004-09-01HONDAACCORD I CTDI SPORTN22A1N22A1101327402204103BLUE0001-01-0100HEAVY OIL4 DOOR SALOON00001302013-05-092015-03-132013-06-140001-01-012004-09-01200400514300000000000000000197000000000000.0008072030002 AXLE RIGID BODYF£77.00£145.00HondaAccordCTDiSportSaloonDieselCarFamily45Manual5164x2FrontN22A1TransverseFront4Inline22042.2140103TurboCL, CMFA2003-03-012005-12-01RHD2670mmUnited KingdomHONDAACCORDACCORD DIESEL SALOONSportSaloonManualDiesel2.2i CTDi Sport 4dr
```

How make them appear in html template sorted and nice view?

Sorry I am noob!

Comment: What is a "nice view"? With line breaks?

Comment: Use `echo htmlentities($resp)` to see the XML literally.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace $vrm by `$_GET['vrm']` and then you can create html page with a form

```
<form action="yourscript.php" method="GET">
  <input name="vrm" type="text"/>
  <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I get this Notice: Undefined variable: vrm in C:\xampp\htdocs\vrmlookup.php on line 22
An error has occurred.

Comment: @NilsJoksts did you replace $vrm in line `'http://localhost/somethings?vrm='.$vrm`?

Answer (score 0):

To see the output nicely, use:

```
echo '<pre>' . htmlentities($resp) . '</pre>';
```

For the first question, you need to do research and learn how to write HTML forms and process them with PHP. SO is not a tutoring service.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks panel, works perfectly,

I added echo '

```
' . htmlentities($resp) . '
```

';

And response appears

```html
<vehicle><identifiers><vrm>SK54OOV</vrm><vin>JHMCN15204C212979</vin><gcode><id>21250</id><code>GBRC0090001FA00BAARAL4FTI040220410316BCFDC0505OTHER02670022004122005</code></gcode><thirdparty><autodata><code>HON14361</code></autodata><techdoc><code /></techdoc><cap><id>26199</id><code>HOAC22SPO4SDTM  1</code><alternatives><cap><ID>26200</ID><Code>HOAC22SP74SDTM  1</Code></cap></alternatives></cap><edi /></thirdparty></identifiers><dvladata><cherishedtransfer><marker>1</marker><date /><previousvrm /></cherishedtransfer><registrationdate><firstregistration>2004-09-01</firstregistration><firstregistrationuk>2004-09-01</firstregistrationuk></registrationdate><manufacturer>HONDA</manufacturer><model>ACCORD I CTDI SPORT</model><engine><code>N22A1</code><number>N22A11013274</number><size><cc>02204</cc></size><power><kw>103</kw></power></engine><colour><current>BLUE</current><lastcolourchangedate>0001-01-01</lastcolourchangedate><previouscolourcount>00</previouscolourcount></colour><fuel>HEAVY OIL</fuel><bodystyle>4 DOOR SALOON</bodystyle><history><export><marker>0</marker></export><import><marker>0</marker><northernireland><marker>0</marker></northernireland></import><scrap><marker>0</marker></scrap><vin><marker>1</marker></vin><previousownercount>3</previousownercount><priorregistrationuse>0</priorregistrationuse><previouskeeper><acquisitiondate>2013-05-09</acquisitiondate><disposaldate>2015-03-13</disposaldate></previouskeeper><v5cchangedate>2013-06-14</v5cchangedate><victest><date>0001-01-01</date><result /></victest></history><manufacturedate>2004-09-01</manufacturedate><manufactureyear>2004</manufactureyear><vinbuildmonth /><seatcount>005</seatcount><co2emissionsgkm>143</co2emissionsgkm><weightkg><gross>0000000</gross><unladen>000000000</unladen><fullyladen>01970</fullyladen><maxtowingbraked>00000</maxtowingbraked><maxtowingunbraked>00000</maxtowingunbraked></weightkg><powertoweightratio>0.00</powertoweightratio><noisedb><stationary>080</stationary><driveby>72</driveby><engine>03000</engine></noisedb><wheelplan>2 AXLE RIGID BODY</wheelplan><roadfundlicense><band>F</band><sixmonth>£77.00</sixmonth><twelvemonth>£145.00</twelvemonth></roadfundlicense></dvladata><enhanceddata><gcodedata><manufacturer>Honda</manufacturer><model>Accord</model><modeldescription /><specdescription>CTDi</specdescription><derivative>Sport</derivative><bodystyle>Saloon</bodystyle><fueltype>Diesel</fueltype><category>Car</category><class>Family</class><doorcount>4</doorcount><seatcount>5</seatcount><transmissiontype>Manual</transmissiontype><gearcount>5</gearcount><valvecount>16</valvecount><driveaxle>4x2</driveaxle><drivetype>Front</drivetype><engine><code>N22A1</code><alignment>Transverse</alignment><position>Front</position><cylinder><count>4</count><configuration>Inline</configuration></cylinder><size><cc>2204</cc><litre>2.2</litre></size><power><bhp>140</bhp><kw>103</kw></power><fueldelivery>Turbo</fueldelivery><emission /></engine><modelversioncode>CL, CM</modelversioncode><modelversion>FA</modelversion><specdaterange><from>2003-03-01</from><to>2005-12-01</to></specdaterange><steeringposition>RHD</steeringposition><weightkg><gross /></weightkg><wheelbasemm>2670mm</wheelbasemm><country>United Kingdom</country></gcodedata><capdata><manufacturer>HONDA</manufacturer><model>ACCORD</model><variantdescription>ACCORD DIESEL SALOON</variantdescription><derivative>Sport</derivative><bodystyle>Saloon</bodystyle><transmissiontype>Manual</transmissiontype><fueltype>Diesel</fueltype><description>2.2i CTDi Sport 4dr</description></capdata></enhanceddata></vehicle>
```

How to get them look like that, make some customization from curl output?

http://postimg.org/image/6t9fp44p9/